What is the rationale for the 6n+2 rule for pi bonds in a noncyclic molecule? That is, why does it work?
In several websites there is a rule of thumb to determine the number of pi bonds in a non-cyclic molecule called the "6n+2 rule", in which n = the number of non-hydrogen atoms in the molecules, and V = total number of valence electrons, so that the number of electrons involved in pi bonds is 6n+2-V (i.e., the number of pi bonds is (6n+2-V)/2. This rule was introduced in the article "Lewis Structures and the octet rule. An automatic procedure for writing canonical forms." by Lever, A.B.P. in the J.Chem Educ. 1972. 49(12), pages 819-821. Unfortunately, there is a paywall to this article, and none of the websites which are freely available explain why the rule (generally) works. I considered that the number 6 might have something to do with a maximum of three sigma bonds around an atom and the 2 to do with a hydrogen bond, but that didn't pan out. (Also, the examples tend to be organic molecules, but is this necessary?) In short, why does the rule work (when it works)? Thanks very much for any pointers.

Can you give us an example?

Links to the "several websites" would be useful

Of course it's for organic molecules. Very similar to degree of unsaturation thingy.

Ivan Neretin and Ian Bush: for example,
https://lavelle.chem.ucla.edu/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21592
and
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/365510043_A_Simple_Approach_for_Beginners_to_Drawing_Lewis_Structures_Resonance_Forms_and_Isomers/fulltext/637e75442f4bca7fd0854a07/A-Simple-Approach-for-Beginners-to-Drawing-Lewis-Structures-Resonance-Forms-and-Isomers.pdf
Mithoron and whoever voted my question down: yes, I appreciate that my question may sound silly to a chemistry person, but Chemistry is  not my field.

To all: my own attempt at an answer is to imagine constructing a molecule like a puzzle with pieces (atoms) each with three arms (sigma bonds) around it, thereby the 6n, and then to construct the molecule which would obey the octet rule, one would need one extra arm, hence the 2. Valid?
